# Need assistance with a SQL query, how do I loop a result and omitting the first record?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named User with a list of names in that table.  I want to run a single SQL string that returns a list of names without the name of the first record in consecutive order. The omitted name will be the column's header.

I have tried:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM user AND NOT (name = 'David')");<br>
```

and<

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM user (LIMIT 1)");
```

The 1st result should be:

```
Tim
Jeremy
Mike
David
```

With the name `Roberto` being omitted.

The 2nd result should be:

```
Roberto
Jeremy
Mike
David
```

With the name `Tim` being omitted.

The 3rd result should be:

```
Roberto
Tim
Mike
David
```

With the name `Jeremy` being omitted.

And so on..

Comment: I am using PHP 5.5, I have tried to use 7.2 but had issues connecting to MySQL database.

Comment: That's because you're using a database API that's a decade out of date.

Comment: The keyword for a `WHERE` clause is, well, `WHERE`, not `AND` as in "`SELECT name FROM user AND NOT (name = 'David')`". But apart from that what columns defines the order on the table? And why are do you want to do this? Maybe such queries are not the best answer to your actual problem.

Comment: Thank you for your responses.  The idea is to build a versus table.  Each tabled result belongs to the omitted name.  For example:

Table Header: Roberto
Table Data:
versus Tim
versus Jeremy
versus Mike
versus David

Comment: *"I have tried to use 7.2 but had issues connecting to MySQL database"* - That's because you're using a mysql api that is no longer supported in that version of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can join the table with itself, and use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get all the other names.

```
SELECT u1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(u2.name) AS others
FROM user AS u1
JOIN user AS u2 ON u2.name != u1.name
```

`others` will be a comma-separated list of all the other names. So it will look like:

```
name    others
Roberto Tim,Jeremy,Mike,David
Tim     Roberto,Jeremy,Mike,David
Jeremy  Roberto,Tim,Mike,David
Mike    Roberto,Tim,Jeremy,David
David   Roberto,Tim,Jeremy,Mike
```

You can then use `explode()` in PHP to split it into an array.

If you have lots of names, make sure you set `group_concat_max_len` high enough to allow all the names.